# some doubts about the integration rules

Tags: integration

$$\int_a^b$$
is said to be equivalent to 
$$\int_a^c\ + \int_c^b$$
is this only true when c is in [a, b] or c is any arbitrary number? If so How, because, most possibly the function may no even be continuous outside of [a, b].

and if yes, I don't understand the following:
f(x) = x over any closed [a, b], 0 < a < b.

$$\int_a^b\ x dx\ =\int_a^0\ xdx\ +\int_0^b\ xdx$$
here we can see that c does not belong to [a, b], but this particular expression is derived to :
$$\int_0^1 x^2 \,dx= \frac{b^2}{2}\ -\frac{a^2}{2}$$

which is an established proof.

Comment: The first is true. If you let the indefinite integral of $f(x)$ be $F(x)$, then we see that the first expression is equivalent to
$$F(b)-F(a)$$
and the second is
$$F(c)-F(a)+F(b)-F(c)$$
which is the same as
$$F(b)-F(a)$$

Comment: The identity "$\int_a^b=\int_a^c+\int_c^b$" is meant to be read as: "Let $a,b,c$ bee three real numbers, let $H$ be the smallest closed interval which contains all three of them, and let $f:H\to\Bbb R$ be a Riemann integrable function on the whole $H$. Then, $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\int_a^cf(x)\,dx+\int_c^bf(x)\,dx$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^cf(x)dx+\int_c^bf(x)dx$$ is true when all three integrals are defined (so if $f$ is undefined outside of $[a,b]$, some of the integrals may fail to exist).  See @GSassatelli 's comment above for a more rigorous definition.

Continuity is not required for integrability, there are lots of functions which are integrable, but not continuous.  For example, the function 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\geq 0\\-1&x<0\end{cases}
$$
is integrable, for example
$$
\int_{-2}^1f(x)dx=-1.
$$

The reason that the original equality holds is that the definite integral measures the *signed* area and the extra area if $c$ is outside $[a,b]$, gets cancelled in the two integrals.

Comment: how do we even prove this geometrically given that c lies somewhere outside of [a,b] for which the function may be defined.

Comment: When you write $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ you are not saying that the domain of $f$ is $[a,b]$, only that the domain of $f$ *contains* $[a,b]$.  If you're lucky enough that the domain of $f$ is larger than $[a,b]$ and contains $c$ so that the integrals are defined, then the equality is true.